# Change image name after thumbnail creation

Tags: php

i have this code here which outputs me an image..
I need to change it because for the moment it gives me something like : test.jpg, what i need is for it to give me test_s.jpg

Can you please orient me to how to do it?

Thanks!

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetPath =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath);
$targetFile =  $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function should do what you want.

Comment: @Al_12 did you read the documentation sudowned linked you to?

Comment: The way to stop being a newbie is to try stuff. There are loads of examples on the page I linked you to. Give it a shot, tell us what happens.